# interactive pie chart to deep dive into each category (ideally recursively)

Tags: r, pie-chart

Is there any `R` package (`htmlwidgets`-like) to plot interactive pie charts? (please, do not get me started on the drawbacks of pie chart and its awful Tufte's data-ink ratio; the fact is that pie charts are familiar and actually appreciated by some audiences, so I want to -kind of- overcome pie chart's weaknesses with interactivity to tell a good story to an audience that would like to hear such a story using pie charts).

What I specifically want is to plot a pie chart that:

- Has custom tooltips providing further details
- With one click shows the details of clicked category (ideally using a sub-plot, like an another pie chart, showing how this category breaks down; even more ideally, recursively).

The closest thing I've found is `amPie` from `rAmCharts`. It has some tooltips and when you click a category slices it out. But it does not show any further detail of such category.

Comment: @irudnyts suggestion to use Shiny is a good one despite the intended goal (which I can't comment on further since you don't want visualization choice commentary).

Comment: As suggested by @ProcrastinatusMaximus I put it to the comments:  Should it be necessarily in `R`? If not, one can use `Shiny` and build an web-app, which will have described features.

Comment: thanks, ..., ok, shiny is a good idea, ..., the drawback is that the idea was to have a file (e.g. standard .html) that the presenter can use anywhere (even without internet connection). With Shiny I would need either to install R / RStudio locally or to deploy the Shiny app in a Shiny server (e.g. Shinyapps.io). That's why I was looking for something like `htmlwidgets`-based solution, that I could use in an `RMarkdown` file and end of story (i.e. produces html file that anyone can open and interact with in any browser).

Comment: @hrbrmstr feel free to put your visualization commentary out there; I just didn't want someone to only lecture me on why pie charts are a bad idea and offer no solution. But no worries, put your commentary out there, and if it has idea on how to do this in a more effective way, even better

Comment: If you don't want the heavy dependency on Shiny (which I can understand) then You could look at `flexdashboard` (you may not get the click-on-pie functionality, but you can have tabs for the drill downs and a sidebar with links). I suspect faceted bar charts would treat the data with more respect than interactive pies, but you claim to know your audience and their ability (or lack thereof) to interpret more precise visualizations.

Comment: yeah, faceted bar charts would be certainly more precise, but the audience for this particular project simply like (and are used to) pie charts (even though their ability to objectively interpret those charts may be limited). Actually, for other personal project I had a solution in Shiny with click-on-bar functionality that would be perfect here. But I can't use it because i) Shiny is not a option, 'cause they cannot install everything locally and they do not want to post their business data online; and ii) because they prefer pier charts instead of bars :(

Comment: I haven't tried this `htmlwidget`  https://github.com/mrjoh3/pier yet, but have had good experience with the underlying library d3-pie http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.com/2014/07/beer-and-pie-rcharts-pie-charts-with.html